# Single word for "probably wrong"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I need a word that corresponds to the meaning of "probably wrong" (as said in the title). I can re-phrase my sentence, but I would appreciate it if someone knew of an adjective that fits the statement.

Here's an example of what I mean:
"In her utter confusion, she scrawled the [probably wrong] answers on the paper."

Comment: In her utter confusion, she scrawled **random answers** on the paper.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. This is a fair question. a possible answer might be "questionable".

Comment: She scrawled her ***guesses*** on the paper.

Comment: How about "doubtful"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Takers of multiple choice tests are sometimes advised to [“eliminate **improbable** answers”](https://books.google.com/books?id=d1IDVEUBLCUC&pg=PA18&dq=%22improbable+answers%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiL2tWBlIDXAhVF4iYKHUYgAg0Q6AEILzAB#v=onepage&q=%22improbable%20answers%22&f=false)
(example usage from *Barron's Regents Exams and Answers: Earth science-- the physical setting*, via *GoogleBooks*)

[improbable](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/improbable)
adjective
not likely to be true or to happen; not probable:
an improbable excuse
(from *Cambridge Dictionary*)

In the third edition (2003) of *Webster's New World Thesaurus* By Charlton Laird (also via *GoogleBooks*), [this connection](https://books.google.com/books?id=AG0DnzXy-u4C&pg=PA124&lpg=PA124&dq=improbable+%22probably+wrong%22&source=bl&ots=GY6DiuqOuN&sig=n9MlhYeInvg3JuS8BSsIDzbgGCQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjSmK7rloDXAhVEWBoKHUAfCFwQ6AEIOjAD#v=onepage&q=improbable%20%22probably%20wrong%22&f=false) is made between “[Improbable] [and] probably wrong” in its second entry for “doubtful.”

Comment: A test taker may wish to eliminate improbable answers, but in a larger context, improbable answers are not necessarily *probably wrong*; they are just unlikely.

Comment: @Clare ... Good point!  Bringing *improbable*’s meaning down from “unlikely to be right” (your astute interpretation, which is supported by the definition I cited and which I now share) to something closer to “likely to be wrong” (which was my original take, and what the OP is after) would require (at least) adding “highly” to it, which would no longer be a single word.  In fact, regardless of the closest/best underlying adjective (be it improbable/sketchy/random [guesses]/questionable/doubtful/unlikely), maybe OP should consider adding “highly” to it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider ***sketchy***:

> 1. :of the nature of a sketch :roughly outlined
> 2. :wanting in completeness, clearness, or substance :slight, superficial
>
>    - the details are *sketchy*
> 3. :questionable, iffy
>
>    - got into a *sketchy* situation
>    - a *sketchy* character
>
> <sub>[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sketchy)</sub>